# Alternative methods of blood circulation?

Tags: biology, humans, fauna, flora

So, I've got a parasite, which adapts and grows to keep its (human) host alive. One of the hosts in question has lost their heart, and since the parasite itself, taking the form of vine-like structures, grows alongside the blood vessels anyway, it uses movement and alterations of the blood vessels to keep the blood moving. I wanted to keep the plant theme strong if possible.

Originally, I theorized that they'd use a peristalsis-esque motion to move the blood through however I'm a little unsure a) whether the blood is too thin to work with this and b) how it would keep the same flow rate when going up/against gravity as going down.

I also looked into phloem in plants, given that the skip itself is plant-based, but translocation there relies heavily on loading/unloading and the presence of sinks and sources as opposed to the way blood is mainly cycled and recycled around in the human body. It also requires the presence of xylem and water transfer via osmosis to increase pressure. Since humans just use blood instead of sap and water as plants do, we don't really have that pressure change + xylem/phloem relationship that seems to be a key element here.

I want to avoid making a replacement heart as much as I can, as well as use some kind of motion on the parasite-bloodvessel-combo's part.

The flow rate should be variable e.g. faster when stressed or exercising.

A friend of mine proposed that we just run with the phloem thing and have the parasite form a xylem where the water is intercepted from the intestine where it usually goes to the bloodstream and goes into this separate channel instead. Sinks therefore are the absorption of nutrients into tissue as the body does, and sources are transfer of nutrients from food to the bloodstream/phloem. Would that be... a thing?

Any ideas?

Comment: You want the replacement heart to not be a replacement heart, but it needs to act like a heart including the brain-to-heart feedback? Does your parasite infest the brain and the nervous system such that it can replace that feedback? This feels like a "how do I realistically keep my dead zombie alive?" question. If so, the answer is, "you realistically can't, zombies are dead." I can imagine a plant that wraps around the aorta and squeezes in cyclic rhythm to keep the blood moving (although that's entirely unrealistic, but it would be cool), but regulating blood pressure?

Comment: why do you need blood circulation on the dead? can't your parasites mimic the nervous sys and control the muscle? have you watch how the video where they make the dead frog legs twitch?

Comment: @user6760 they are not dead... everything's alive except for a lack of heart. so i need to circulate nutrients, oxygen, etc. the parasite is, well, lazy, and won't change every system if it doesn't need to.

Comment: @JBH i could say the parasite kind of... intercepts the signals from the nervous system that normally make the heart pump faster/slower? it's moderately integrated i'd say. again, everything is functioning except the heart. the idea is it doesn't act like a heart but uses a mechanism in the blood vessels themselves to pump the blood? as to why no replacement heart itself, it's just because the parasite already grows along the path of the blood vessels.

Comment: Welcome. By way of clarification on an important technical point. If a a 'parasite' is actively providing positive benefits to it;s host (in this case keeping it alive because of the lack of a heart)? It's not parasite anymore it's transitioned to an entirely different environment niche. It's now become a symbiote! And its relationship with the host is symbiotic. Look up the symbiotes and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: (a) I think you're being way too technical about this. Said another way, I think you're focusing on things you don't understand rather than the basics. (b) Is the heart still in place? If so, how will you deal with the closed valves and how will you deal with atrophy reducing the flow capacity? If not... how are you routing the blood between the veins and arteries? What are you doing to stop the hemorrhage caused by the capillary connections to the heart having been severed? And what are you doing about the change in chest cavity density and what that will do to surrounding organs?

Comment: Please don't get me wrong! I think that the basic idea is cool! I just think you're focusing on a bunch of technical stuff that isn't at all relevant until you've dealt with the basic stuff. What worries me is that the details you're worried about seem to indicate you want an incredibly high level of realism... except that the evolution of such a parasite isn't realistic in any way (IMO, I'm not a biologist).

Comment: @JBH Once the heart stopped working, I was going to say that the tissue was broken down and recycled through the parasite, so no, it's not there. It looks like all signs point towards the creation of a more replacement heart-esque growth. The change in chest cavity density is something I will need to think about though as I theorised the vines to be less dense anyway than standard tissue. Also, for a little context, the parasite is actually for the SCP wiki and has a whole lot of background regarding its origin. It's not naturally evolved. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## She's dead Jim

The heart is an essential part for humans to operate <sup>*[citation needed]*</sup>. To state the obvious, it pumps around vital nutrients, hormones and oxygen, together with a host of other things like carriers of oxygen, waste disposal and immune system related things.it is absolutely essential.

The heart works all day, every day. It does not rest like other muscles. It merely has times it us less active. It is neither a light task it does 24/7. To keep up the pace it is a highly specialised organ, with cells capable of sustaining this unrelenting rhythm.

Removing the heart requires a replacement that can pump at least as well as the heart at maximum rest. Your host seems to be still alive and I assume it still needs to be able to take sustenance. It need to be able to sustain both itself and the parasite. The best case scenario is that the host requires minimum effort to do so. What would be needed?

A miracle. Not only should the parasite have planned this in advance, the body is quickly inoperable when the heart goes missing, but it needs to somehow replace an intense pumping function. Plants are famous for their inactivity, barely moving on their own if at all. Let's say it solves that by changing how the human body grows to it's heart replacing needs, what can we do?

Pumping bloid does not need to be centralised. We could do what the intestines do. We line the blood vessels with muscle, moving them rhythmically in a direction to get the blood flowing. There's of course issues. Most large veins aren't meant to be cut off, at least not with such regularity, so we can't just squeeze 100%. This reduces our power greatly, leaving way too little power to pump the blood. But even if we could it can be doubtful to work. Blood vessels are meant to transport blood to tissue. They are not meant to be insulated by pumping muscle. So the veins you can apply this to are mostly the larger ones, which you do not want to squeeze. The whole brain would not have any muscle to pump. The problem of pumping without a heart is simply that without any form of heart you have too little pressure to get a required flow for normal functioning. At best you can grow a sort of distributed heart system, having multiple tiny hearts and all the insane complications that come with it.

Other methods than pumping are simply doomed from the word go. The reason for pumping blood is that animals require an insane amount of energy to run. Look at the requirements of a 100kg plant vs you. One needs more water and nutrients to operate on a daily basis, to a degree that is absolutely staggering. Moving nutrients via anything other than pumping blood will result in the starvation of the cells. They burn up their energy in a short time, not getting a resupply and die.

In other words, no survivors.

### The end?

Surely not. We have a plethora of media that shows you can do whatever you want. Supernatural zombies are accepted without blinking. In Alien the hosts become practically immortal as a creature develops in a time span  that our agriculture would drool at, with acid blood to boot. Animated mud, radioactive/mutated spider bites giving superpowers instead of cancer or necrotic flesh, touching an alien artifact gives premonitions. A person with their lungs burned to a crisp who then has been treated with a bacteria that allowed her to 'breathe through her skin like a plant, even feeding off sunlight and water to sustain herself (which conveniently for fan service required very little clothing). Media is full with suspension of disbelief.

You've already got an idea. Just put it into practice. Sure it might not make sense in our real world, but with hosts being taken over by parasitic organisms we're already primed to suspend our view of reality.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I see that the parasite/symbiote would a) need to be super smart with great knowledge of biology and b) super fast as the time it takes for it to adapt would probably either cause the person to be Very screwed up w. some of their tissue already dying or dead already. I might just run with the replacement-heart, then, that would limit the sapience of the parasite too and just make it copy what died, thereby making it more believable? The plant shenanigans wouldn't function on a big enough scale to run a Whole Human, so I'll drop that.

Comment: Additionally, the nutrition needs -  if I was to go the 'suspension of disbelief' way I'd have it leech kinetic energy from surroundings and the body and drop the temperature, which is kind of a stretch but also interesting imagery. The vines could partly be powered by the human's movement on the side as well? The blood is to keep the body alive. The vines, they are a bit peculiar.

Answer (score 1):

The parasite eats the blood, and vomits, excreets something else back, that almost behaves like blood. Similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirudo_medicinalis but with a waste product that can carry oxygen and stimulate the host to "feel" good, even though he looses tons of nutrients to the parasite.

So how does it do that? The answer is, the victims body runs a marathon every night, in which the parasite stores away tons of oxygen to be carried off by the waste product.The oxygen is stored away in "lumps and bumps" the fruits on the vein of the parasite. So the vitcims swell up at night, wake up "fat" and get ever slimmer throughout the day. Although "fat" at the days start, they of course "hunger" for food and are thus ostracized by society as "never-fed". In its final form the parasite eats enough to feed a whole family and the streched skin turns into enormous sacks dangling in the evening. Thus it was named the "Rags&doll"-parasite.

The blood of a human is produced in bone marrow and and thus, at the veins going away from the extremities, the filter-mouths of the beast lurk and hunger. The only thing a rag&doll victim can never have is a stroke- and there filtered brakish "blood" generally refuses to clot. Cut one and he will bleed vicously for minutes, before a strange, leathery substance repaireth the  the wounded blood vessel. The wound never healeth, but instead becomes a leathery scab. There skin complexion is waxen, but the veins and internal organs seem to have a sun-tan.

They try to infect you by spitting in the food they serve you. Also the growth seems to attracted by smells of violence, accumulating beneath the skin, as if to burst at butcher-shops, leather-tanners and places were crime-perpetrators are drawn and quatered.

Once the parasite has procreated, it withers and dies, trying to get eaten. The host suffocates in long raspy, ragged breath, demanding help from others to revive him. Rapidly the body gives way, to decay that was held up by the parasite. Fungi, pus and filth taketh over the cavities while the victim still yearns for air.

What keept the "blood" flowing, the constrictions of the parasite and the muscle spasms it triggered to compress its "repositories", finally comes to rest, in one last, squeeze, ejecting the fluids, leaving behind a skeletton wrapped in skin.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question for alternative ways to blood circulation. Could you edit the answer to fit the question, or remove it altogether?

Comment: I agree with @Trioxidane, but I can see where your answer could be molded to answer the question. Remember the OP is asking for an explanation of how a parasite could replace the human heart in all its glory, including regulation of blood pressure. Your answer addresses the need to oxygenate the blood, but that need isn't relevant since the lungs still exist and perform that duty. Pushing another material could solve the blood flow/pressure problem, though. Could you massage this to bring it closer to the OP's needs?

Comment: It inflates, and constricts.. that would replace over time the heart?

Comment: @JBH It alternatively could trigger involuntary muscel spasms, compressing the parasite and thus creating a pressure spike in within the "alternative" blood

Comment: :-) Don't tell me, friend! Edit your post and tell everyone.